# Reusable method to check if all objects are unequal using valueForKey

Tags: objective-c, compare

I have been working with this method for hours. It is supposed to simply check if the attribute of the cards passed in as `otherCards` isEqual to the same attribute of this (self) instance of class. But I am tearing my hair out - it is giving false results

```
 (BOOL)otherCards: (NSArray *)otherCards allHaveUnequalAttribute: (NSString *)key
{
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[otherCards valueForKey:key]];
    int countUnequalMatches = 0;

        for (NSNumber *setValue in values) {
            if (![[self valueForKey:key] isEqual:setValue]) {
                countUnequalMatches++;}
        }
    NSLog(@"countUnequalMatches %d values count: %d", countUnequalMatches, [values count]);

    if (countUnequalMatches == [values count]) return  YES ?: NO;
}
```

It is called like this:

```
 if ([self otherCards:otherCards allHaveUnequalAttribute:CARD_SHAPE]) {
        NSLog(@"All unequal");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"One or more card equal");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug myself
if (countUnequalMatches == [values count]) return  YES ?: NO;

should be:
if (countUnequalMatches == [otherCards count]) return  YES ?: NO;

as I used the Set as an way to count unique items.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that predicates are very well suited to handle.

```
-(BOOL)otherCards: (NSArray *)otherCards allHaveUnequalAttribute: (NSString *)key
{
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", key, [self valueForKey:key]];

    NSArray *equalCards = [otherCards filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

    return equalCards.count == 0;
}
```